# Why my label shows "String called name" Null

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have an assignment project for my collage and when i try to show Welcome Label it shows the string as Null. Maybe because it's the initial value of the string which being saved when i run the program yet i can solve that and it faces me a lot

```
public void getData() {
    String username = crntUsername.passUsername();  
    i = crntCustomer.search(username);      
    name = crntCustomer.passName(i);        
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    welcomeLabel.setText("Welcome "+ name);
}
```

[I expect that my String should be shown instead of Null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9hG1.png)

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am going to guess that you need to run the `getData` code in your `initialize` method before the `welcomeLabel` statement.

Comment: `initialize` is called while loading the fxml. At that time `getData` cannot possibly be called unless you do the call in a initializer/the constructor. If you did this in the constuctor, none of the nodes from the fxml would be available...

Comment: it can't be done or what then?